# Uber Request API: Unable to get "request" scope

Tags: uber-api

Every time I make a request to the sandbox using the /requests endpoint, I get a "Missing scope: request" error. I've double checked and triple checked that I'm requesting the correct scope in the auth request:

```
{'scopes': u'profile,history,request', 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/submit', 'response_type': 'code'}
```

In the reply I get back from the server with the Auth token, it very clearly skips the request scope.

```
{u'last_authenticated': 1455088324, u'access_token': u'XX', u'expires_in': 2592000, u'token_type': u'Bearer', u'scope': u'profile history', u'refresh_token': u'XX'}
```

I've verified that I'm using the same account to authenticate as my developer account.

One possible issue, if I look at the developer console, it doesn't let me select the "request" scope. The checkbox is disabled. Could this be the problem? How do I enable it?

What else could I be missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs on the [authorize endpoint](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize) says about the scope parameter:

> scope (optional)  Space delimited list of grant scopes you would like
>   to have permission to access on behalf of the user.

- Your scope request parameter should have the [scopes](https://developer.uber.com/docs/scopes) **space delimited**, not comma delimited!
- Make sure that the HTTP GET parameter you are sending is called **scope**, not scopes!
- Make sure you are [percent/URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) all the query string parameters you are sending!

The request scope works in sandbox mode only by default.
To enable it in production mode you have to request access from Uber by using the contact form present in the [Uber Developers dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) specific to the app you have created on Uber.

Comment: Looks like the problem was "scope" not "scopes", although I swear I tried the same solution two weeks ago and it didn't work (it would give me a"scope" parameter is unknown error, maybe temporary glitch in the API). In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mnemonic Flow as per you answer **https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={{client id}}&response_type=code&scope=profile%20history_lite%20history%20request** But no luck for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Open your browser in incognito mode
2) Hit the authorization endpoint, but make sure you're encoding the params in the url itself as query params
3) Make sure you're separating the scopes you want to request with spaces, not commas (I think thats the main issue you're running into)

If you do that, you should see an authorization screen with all scopes you're requesting and one of them should be the request scope :)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those worked. Here is the authoriez URL that is being generated, can you see anythng wrong with it?  https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?scopes=profile+history+request+all_trips&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fuber%2Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=XXXX